# Matplotlib labels are not fully displayed

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

[image]

The labels are cut off from the picture. You can only view them partially.
How can you make the label appear fully?

```
pyplot.style.use('ggplot')

y = -30
x = 70
ax2 = pyplot.gca()

pyplot.plot(powerdemand, linewidth=2.0)
pyplot.plot(middle, linewidth=4.0)

ax2.set_xlabel('Time in s')
ax2.set_ylabel('Power consumption in MW')
pyplot.ylim(y,x)
# Place a legend to the right of this smaller figure.
pyplot.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=4,
           ncol=1, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)



for label in ax2.get_xticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)
for label in ax2.get_yticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)

pyplot.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=True)

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 23})

pyplot.savefig("/Users/user/Desktop/test.png")
```

Comment: `fig = plt.gcf(); fig.tight_layout()`

Answer (score -3):

Try `bbox_index` when saving the fig:

```
pyplot.savefig("/Users/user/Desktop/test.png",bbox_index='tight')
```